# Installing a new SSD (to replace my HDD) But not working

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, sata

So recently my HDD had a failure and I had to replace it. I bought a new SSD and it arrived today.
I took out my HDD and put in the SSD and when I went to boot up my computer (to install windows and all the good stuff) it gave me this

"Check cable connection!
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM

Reboot and select proper boot device or insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"

So not sure what to do about this. The one thing I notice is I believe my HDD was a little bit taller than the SSD but they are both Sata 3 so I dont know if that makes a difference or not
Here is a link to the spec of my HDD, I will include a pic of the order of my PC from Xotic pc (maybe more info there) and a pic of the specs on the SSD I got.

[TS-7K1000-ds (HDD)](https://www.hgst.com/sites/default/files/resources/TS-7K1000-ds.pdf)

[image]

Comment: You need to check/change the order of your boot devices in the BIOS. Boot into your BIOS, check the boot order, and place the SSD as the first boot option.

Answer (score 1):

The [PXE ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) message is related to your system trying to boot from the network, since it couldn't find a bootable hard drive.

Make sure the drive is hooked up properly and detected by your BIOS (and in the right place in the boot order).  Then boot from bootable Windows installation media and install your OS.

Comment: Ok so I've noticed that after putting in my Windows CD, the computer was able to boot from CD. Now, I'm in the installing part.  As far as I can tell, it sees the SSD and it's named Disk 0 un-allocated space so I will try to install it on that and see if it works. But thank you for your reply.

Comment: If Windows' setup is seeing it as Disk 0 that's fully unallocated then it sounds like it's working as expected now. :)